# Can I user LOWER and MIN in the same SQL query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I am getting an issue with my query written, am I able to use a LOWER and a MIN In the same query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LOWER(id_5) AS "ID"
    ,MIN(visittime) AS "First Date"
FROM table
WHERE (date >= '2022-11-21')
    AND (
        server = 'pets.com' AND page = 'pets:dogs:puppy')
```

Comment: this would only return one row, but of course you can use them together.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting? The `DISTINCT` is unnecessary/superfluous.

Comment: What is the issue/error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MIN`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html?highlight=min#min) is aggregation function which can be used only with aggregation or as [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) or scenarios reducible to this like in queries when only one row is expected:

```
select max(LOWER(id_5)) AS "ID" -- or any other aggregation  function
   , min(Status) AS "First Date"
from dataset;
```

which is equivalent to `group by true`.

Note that `DISTINCT` works on all values in the select. If you want to find first visit per unique `id_5` then just use `group by`:

```sql
SELECT LOWER(id_5) AS "ID"
    , MIN(visittime) AS "First Date"
FROM table
WHERE (date >= '2022-11-21')
    AND (
        server = 'pets.com' AND page = 'pets:dogs:puppy')
group by LOWER(id_5)
```